# How can I send a Document with telegram bot API?

Tags: python-requests, python-telegram-bot

Good morning everybody. I'd like to send a document using Python and the API from Telegram Bot. The Bot has been successfully created and I can also send messages, but unfortunately I'm not managing to send documents that are on my Laptop.

My Code is the following:

```
import requests


def telegram_bot_send_document():

    bot_token = '####'
    bot_chatID = '####'

    file = open('test.txt', 'rb')
    send_document = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendDocument?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&multipart/form-data=' + str(file.read())

    r = requests.post(send_document)
    print(r.url)

    return r.json()
```

The Output is always:

```
{'ok': False, 'error_code': 400, 'description': 'Bad Request: there is no document in the request'}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all of the above and spent a day searching for the right answer to the question but found nothing anywhere. Weird!
But finally after testing and modifying the answer of @Nengha here's my solution that works perfectly fine.

```
def telegram_bot_send_document():

bot_token = ""
bot_chatId = ""

file_location = 'test.txt'
send_document = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token +'/sendDocument?'
data = {
  'chat_id': bot_chatId,
  'parse_mode':'HTML',
  'caption':'This is my file'
}
# Need to pass the document field in the files dict
files = {
    'document': open(file_location, 'rb')
}

r = requests.post(send_document, data=data, files=files, stream=True)
print(r.url)

return r.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

Though its late, I thought I must share for others who might face the same problem as I did.

From Antonio's code there are two major modifications:

#### Passing stream=True in post()

When uploading files, requests requires us to pass the stream=True parameter so that the file can be downloaded on the server side. You can read more about it [Here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/). Also, since it is a post request with multipart/form-data, we are required to pass the data parameter which carries the data(chat_id, caption, parse_mode etc) as well as the files parameter which carries the document in binary.

#### Opening the file within post()

This is weird and I have not found out why, but when I opened my file into a varible like `file = open('text.txt','rb)` and reference it in files parameter like `requests.post(url, data=data, files=file)`, Telegram would throw a Bad Request saying no document found, But when I opened the file within the files parameter like `requests.post(url, data=data, files=open('text.txt','rb'))`, It worked fine.

So the final code should look like this:

```
import requests


def telegram_bot_send_document():

    bot_token = '####'
    bot_chatId = '####'

    open('test.txt', 'rb')
    send_document = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token +'/sendDocument?'
    data = {
      'chat_id': bot_chatId,
      'parse_mode':'HTML',
      'caption':'This is my file'
       }

    r = requests.post(send_document, data=data, files=open('test.txt','rb'),stream=True)
    print(r.url)

    return r.json()
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I have never used the telegramm API oder send documents with telegram.

From their documentation:

(source: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files)

> Sending files There are three ways to send files (photos, stickers,
> audio, media, etc.):
>
> 1. If the file is already stored somewhere on the Telegram servers, you
>    don't need to reupload it: each file object has a file_id field,
>    simply pass this file_id as a parameter instead of uploading. There
>    are no limits for files sent this way.
> 2. Provide Telegram with an HTTP
>    URL for the file to be sent. Telegram will download and send the file.
>    5 MB max size for photos and 20 MB max for other types of content.
> 3. Post the file using multipart/form-data in the usual way that files
>    are uploaded via the browser. 10 MB max size for photos, 50 MB for
>    other files.

You need to upload first the file and reference the ID or you need a `POST`-Request, not attached to the `URL`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. If I don't attach the file to the url how can I upload it?
I read the documentation and I'd like to use the third way: Posting the file using multipart/form-data.